# Confused about Func, Delegates and Anonymous types

Tags: c#, delegates, func

Reading this line of code example from a book:

```
Func<string,int> returnLength;
returnLength = delegate (string text) { return text.Length; };

Console.WriteLine(returnLength("Hello"));
```

It says

> `Func<string,double,int>` is equivalent to a delegate type of the form
>   `public delegate int SomeDelegate(string arg1, double arg2)`

So `Func` is a delegate? Then what is that delegate we have defined again in the code example?
We define a variable from a `Func` that is like a `delegate` and then assign it again to another `delegate`? I am super confused and can't understand this concept. :(

Can someone explain it?

Comment: Func is a delegate with some return type..

Comment: I can't see any anonymous type in your code.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek: `returnLength` is assigned an anonymous *delegate*. OP is confused and used the term "anonymous *type*" instead.

Comment: @Gabe OK, I see it now. But to be 100% correct, thing he refers to is called *anonymous **method***, not *anonymous **delegate***. See MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yw3tz5k.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**So `Func` is a delegate?**

Yes, it's defined as follows:

```cs
public delegate TResult Func<in T, out TResult>(T arg)
```

It's described as:

> Encapsulates a method that has one parameter and returns a value of
>   the type specified by the `TResult` parameter.

Read [Func Delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more.

**Then what is that delegate we have defined again in the code example?**

That's the [anonymous method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yw3tz5k.aspx) we create to assign it to the `Func`-typed variable. You could use named method or [lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) as well, as long as the input and return types match the `Func` generic parameters.

**We define a variable from a Func that is like a delegate and then assign it again to another delegate?**

No, we create a variable **typed as** `Func<string, int>` and then create a delegate matching that type and assign it to the variable.

---

Additional sources from MSDN:

- [Anonymous Functions (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882516.aspx)
- [Anonymous Methods (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yw3tz5k.aspx)
- [Delegates with Named vs. Anonymous Methods (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98dc08ac.aspx)
- [Lambda Expressions (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

the same code you could just write

```
Func<string,int> returnLength = (s) => {return s.Length;}
```

assigning delegate to a `Func` is just like assigning a variable to another..

Answer (score 1):

Your code can also be expressed like this:

```
Func<string,int> returnLength = delegate (string text) { return text.Length; };

Console.WriteLine(returnLength("Hello"));
```

A func is a delegate.

1. `Func<string, int>` is the declaration,
2. `delegate (string text) { return text.Length; }` is the function that you are assigning.

   1. This delegate (function) accepts a string (`string text`) and returns an integer (`return text.Length;`).

This would return `5` as the text.Length of "Hello" is 5.  It is not as you are creating 2 delegates in this example, rather you are just assigning one.

Answer (score 1):

Yes a `Func` is equivalent to a `delegate` type with a return type. The `delegate` you have defined is the `delegate` that is executed when the method is called returning the `int` type.

This can be shortcutted down to

```
Func<string, int> returnLength = (text) => { return text.length; };
```

In this situation the delegate returns a value type of int (Int32)

Now Action is also a delegate type without a return value such as.

```
Action<string> action = delegate(string text) { text = ""; };
```

or

```
Action<string> action = (text) => { text = ""; };
```

Now anonymous types are much different than a `delegate`, `Action` or `Func`. Now `Func` & `Action` were implemented in .Net 3.5 after delegates were introduced.